# How do I use backticks to change directories?

Tags: ruby, shell, irb, backticks

I tried to change directories by using backticks in Ruby. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 box and this is the error I get:

```
irb(main):003:0> `cd /`
(irb):3: command not found: cd /
=> ""
```

I run the command directly via the terminal and I change directories just fine. It also works fine on my local Mac box, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: not sure why `cd /` does not work, but `cd '/'` works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run shell commands using the tick marks, they will be run in a child process that can not change the working directory of the parent.

If you link the `cd` command with another command, you will see it work, but only effecting the child process:

```
`cd / && ls`
```

To change the working directory of the parent process use the Ruby command `Dir.chdir([string])`:

```
Dir.chdir("/")
```

Relevant information can be found in this post:
"[exec the cd command in a ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410310/exec-the-cd-command-in-a-ruby-script)"